# Adding numbers to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a scanner that scans 10 numbers in a String separated by a space. Such as this:

3 4 5 12 32 32 23 54 65 67.
Then I want to parse each numbers into int, and store each number in a int array. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

```
    String numbers;
    int num[] = new num[10];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Type something.");
    numbers = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Hmmm. And what if you want to do it by commas and not spaces? or periods? or question marks. I think split is a much better method as it gives you more options.

Comment: I tried your code. Types in a line and nothing happens.

Comment: lol. Did you actually tested the codes yourself? All i got from the outputs are: num0
num0
num0
num0
num0
num0
num0
num0
num0
num0

Comment: Idea is to give a gist of the fact that scanner has functionality to use delimiter. Have corrected for u again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are on the same line you can use the split function to create an array of strings and then cast them to int.

```
String[] numbersSplit = numbers.split();

for(int i = 0; i < numbersSplit.length; i++) {
    num[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersSplit[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But how do you say 1 or more spaces in java?

Comment: you can always add a regex to the split function refer to this documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: well you don't have to use split. Scanner does not automatically for you

Comment: I learn better by examples. Can you give me an example of using a regex to split it by whitespaces, or commas?

Comment: for white spaces you can use .split("\\s+"); and for comas you can use .split(",");

Comment: What if you want to use both? Do you just seperated them with a colon like this? .split("\\s+":",")

Comment: if you want this or this use can use .split("\\s+|,") if you a space before or after the comma .split("\\s*,\\s*")

Answer (score 1):

Scanner by default uses whitespace as delimiter. so you can try the below.Added a system out just to prove the theory.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num[] = new int[10];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    while (scan.hasNext("\\d+")) {
        num[i] = scan.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("num" + num[j]);
    }

}
```

If you have delimiter other than space, use syntax like this.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(pattern);
```

PS: press any character to escape from loop.